# How to improve on this solution (C++ array iteration)?

Tags: c++, loops, optimization

This is my solution to the problem of finding a value inside a C++ array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Answer
{
public:
    static bool exists(int ints[], int size, int k)
    {
        bool result = false;        
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (ints[i] == k)
                result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

The grader took points off citing the following reasons:
[image: img]

What could I have done to meet their requirements?

Comment: is the input array sorted?

Comment: Do you understand what "binary search" is?  If so, your code doesn't do that, and I see a big red `X` on the item marked as such.

Comment: The second thing is that you keep looping after you've found a result.  At the very least, you should break out of the loop when you find the value.

Comment: Re: "What could I have done to meet their requirements?"  Normally reading the question carefully helps a lot with this.

Answer (score 1):

You are not implementing binary search, you could use binary_search or do it manually:

binary_search:

```cpp
class Answer
{
public:
    static bool exists(int ints[], int size, int k)
    {
      return binary_search(ints, ints + size, k);
    }
};
```

manually:

```cpp
class Answer
{
public:
    static bool exists(int ints[], int size, int k)
    {
      int low = 0;
      int high = size - 1;
      while (low <= high)
      {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if (ints[mid] == k)
        {
          return true;
        }
        else if (ints[mid] < k)
        {
          low = mid + 1;
        }
        else
        {
          high = mid - 1;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
};
```